# Sub-site collection custom navigation

Tags: navigation, sub-site

I manage a sub-site collection of 41 pages within my company's SharePoint 2010. I need to create site navigation for this collection only. I am not allowed to edit the Global navigation or Quick Navigation. Currently, I've created a right side web part for navigation on each page that needs updating whenever a menu change is made.

Is there any way to create a central navigation solely for my sub-site collection, that is independent from the Global Navigation?

Comment: Are you using teams sites or publishing sites?